# Can't build Iron hello world on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, rust, iron

I'm trying to build the [Iron hello world example](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/), but have a problem with OpenSSL.

My OS is Windows 1 and I have tried Rust stable (1.7) and nightly (1.9).

I've [installed OpenSSL with mingw](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl#windows) and set the environment variables `OPENSSL_LIB_DIR` and `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR`. Just in case, I've added the paths to the `PATH` variable. None of these changes fix the problem.

Cargo's output like in this question: [compilation of openssl-sys fails with `openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000685/compilation-of-openssl-sys-fails-with-openssl-hmac-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys-extras v0.7.6`
Process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\sharp_000\Dropbox\Код\Rust\MTFQ\target\release\build\openssl-sys-extras-52d5315fb71d3c6d\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
thread '<main>' panicked at 'explicit panic', C:\Users\sharp_000\.cargo\registry\src\githubcom-88ac128001ac3a9a\gcc-0.3.25\src\lib.rs:818
```

I copied the `include/openssl` directory, `libssl32.dll`, and `libeay32.dll` to the Cargo directory and output changes to:

```
cc1.exe: fatal error: Files/mingw/include: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
thread '<main>' panicked at 'explicit panic', C:\Users\sharp_000\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a\gcc-0.3.25\src\lib.rs:818
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Deleting the `target` directory before building doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Rust edition are you using? I had the same problem with the Rust MSVC edition.

I installed GCC with MSYS2 and changed Rust to the GNU edition, added `gcc` to my `PATH` and everything was OK.

Comment: I tried both GNU and MSVC. When You say "add the gcc to PATH" do You mean add "msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions" where "gcc" file placed? I added it and "msys64\usr\bin" too, also switched to GNU edition, but problem still here.

Comment: Cargo output became: ```--- stderr
cc1.exe: fatal error: Files/mingw/include: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
thread '<main>' panicked at 'explicit panic', C:\Users\sharp_000\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a\gcc-0.3.25\src\lib.rs:818```

Comment: the gcc path depend on which arch you used,
i use mingw64, so the gcc is at C:\MSYS64\mingw64\bin, the another one is mingw32.

Comment: 1) install MSYS2, and install gcc, pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc, and add C:\MSYS64\mingw64\bin to PATH
2) install rust gnu
3) edit Cargo.toml, 
[dependencies]
iron = "*"

the cargo will build everything that iron depend on

Comment: sorry, it also need install mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl